# perl regex to replace 2 substrings

Tags: regex, perl

I wrote a perl snippet that strips `http://` and `www` from the front of a domain name input from the console

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

print "Enter the domain name to be queried:\n";
my $input_domain = <>;
chomp ($input_domain);

my $inter_domain = $input_domain =~ s/http:\/\///r;
my $domain = $inter_domain =~ s/www.//r;

print $domain."\n";
```

When `http://domain-name.tld` or `http://www.domain-name.tld` or even*`www.domain-name.tld` is entered, this code returns `domain-name.tld`.

The question I have is, can the same be achieved using a Perl one-liner that combines both the search and replace lines into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make both the `http://` and the `www.` optional but look for both of them then it will remove either one or both. The only disparity from the original code is that it will change `www.http://domain-name.tld` to `http://domain-name.tld` which I think isn't a disadvantage

It seems odd to ask for a on-liner that modifies user input, so I've written this sample that processes four different strings from the `DATA` file handle. Also note that it's much tidier to use different delimiters for the substitution to avoid having to escape the slashes

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  s|^(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?||;
  print;
}


__END__
http://www.domain-name.tld
http://domain-name.tld
www.domain-name.tld
domain-name.tld
```

#### output

```
domain-name.tld
domain-name.tld
domain-name.tld
domain-name.tld
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the regex: `(http:\/\/)|(www\.)`

`s/(http:\/\/)|(www\.)//r;`

This removes http:// and/or www.

Comment: That will make only one or the other substitution. It will change `http://www.domain-name.tld` into `www.domain-name.tld` which isn't what is wanted